# Why is one of my dogs biting the other one?

Tags: aggression, biting, large-dogs

I just adopted two siblings. Around 1 year old both of them. They are labradoodles. They have always been together and never had any aggression problems. The female dog has been playing really rough lately. More than normal. And we notice that she stared biting him, on the neck and paws. To the point that she hurt him a little bit and left him limping. Why is this happening? What should I do? Does it have to do anything with their heat period.

Comment: Welcome at pets.SE! Are one or both dogs neutered?

Comment: None of them are. I’m getting educated to make a choice of to get one of them neutered and when. If you have any advice..

Comment: As how you discribe it, we can only guess WHY the dogs in this special case act like this. But as you yourself noticed, they would propably calm down with each other if one or both of them is/are neutered. Because you will not breed siblings and you do not want to separate them a lot of times in their life (they will be really smart to find each other and whine and dig and stress themself, do not eat and similar) you should go to the vet soon.